# bcdedit issue? M.2 SATA to NVME clone: Windows 10 won't boot

Tags: hard-drive, uefi, clone, bcdedit, nvme

**Problem:** Windows partition won't boot after cloning M.2 SATA drive to M.2 NVME.

**Background:** Cloning process was simple raw dd copy. Drive had EFI, Windows 10, and Linux partitions. Cloning preserved exact partition sequence, sizes, and UUIDs.

Linux partition needed minor tweaks to /etc/fstab due to the device names being different (/dev/nvme0n1px vs. /dev/sdax), but boots fine.

The disk is GPT, and I believe the original Windows 10 was UEFI - the Linux installation definitely was.

**Attempts at solution:** I did a fresh Windows install in a spare partition and it boots fine. I've edited the BCD entry for my original Win 10 install. I have the correct BCD device, osdevice, and path.

**Questions:** What else needs to be done to make Windows boot again? Are there any config file or registry changes that need to be made to account for the SATA to NVME move?

Comment: I *think* this is sufficiently clarified. How does it get off hold?

Comment: Are you getting any error while booting from Windows partition? Are you using Grub? Was grub able to detect the cloned Window?

Comment: Could it be a missing driver issue? Are you suing m.2 PCH SATA or m.2 PCH PCIE?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer, as far as I ever determined:** Windows (at least at that time) does NOT have NVME drivers by default, and only installs them if it detects NVME during installation. I'm not sure how to boot windows in a SATA configuration and add NVME drivers.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1633804/1686